# Converting designs from photoshop/flash/after effects into code

Tags: animation, interface

I work as part of a two person team, I am the developer and my partner is the designer. We are currently having great difficulty working out the best way to convert his work into the actual app. We prototype all our animation in either Flash or After Effects and then I implement it into the actual application.

The implementation is not a problem, but converting the information is what we are struggling to do efficiently. We have tried making large story boards that show the change in position/scale/rotation and the time for each of these tweens but they are time consuming to make. Currently I am running an After Effects trial and just dissecting the info straight from his design but my trial will run out soon.

Just wondering if anyone can shed some light on how they do it or what is the standard practice in the industry?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "animations"? If that's cutscenes, then export videos. If that's character animations, look for some character animation library, such as [Granny](http://www.radgametools.com/granny.html)... Please describe a bit more what you're talking about.

Comment: No its more like the way menus animate in rr scenes flow from one to another. For things like character animation we just use a sprite sheet. The animations I am talking about are based on tweening objects.

Comment: OK, so we're talking about menu transitions... For Flash content, there's a bunch of tools that can import SWF stuff directly in a game, with some binding work. [Scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform/features/overview) is the big player, but it's no cheap product for a team of two. But there's [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/textweb.pl?path=geekstuff/gameswf.txt) too, which is free. Would that answer your needs?

Comment: Thank you, that is good information. Scaleform looks like what I was thinking but obviously too expensive! Guess we will just stick to what we are doing.

Comment: Have you considered writing a simple tool that takes, say, 2 pictures -- then let the designer define a very limited bunch of transition effects & timings using input boxes/ dropdowns?

Comment: I have. I think this might be the way to go. I was also thinking of adding some sort of LUA engine on top as the designer I work with knows LUA and then he could code the animation himself.

Comment: Do you mean exporting real-time animation like this one?
[Game development with After Effects: Exporting a real-time animation](http://youtu.be/mkF_de_dxOA)

Comment: This is very broad; can you provide more details to narrow down your requirements? The general answer will probably be along the lines of "write some kind of exporter from your design format into your game's data format," but without more information it's hard to be more specific than that.